# The relationship between fisher information and EM algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, algorithms, optimization

I wonder what is the relationship between fisher information and EM algorithm?
When I read papers about EM algorithm, people sometimes discussed about fisher information, and there are algorithms which would combine fisher scoring method and EM algorithm together. However, I couldn't find materials clearly illustrate how fisher information is related to EM algorithm and what role it is playing ?

Could anyone help me understand if there is any connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are connected via the [Cramer-Rao lower bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound). This gives the minimum possible variance of an unbiased estimator as the reciprocal of the Fisher information for $\theta$, $I(\theta)$.

Perhaps more usefully, the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ converges in distribution to $N(\theta, 1/I(\theta))$. I.e., we can write:

$$\hat\theta_n \approx N\left(\theta,\frac{1}{I(\theta)}\right), \;\mbox{as}\; n\rightarrow\infty$$

where $\hat\theta_n$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ based on a random sample of size $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot TooTone !  I got your point.  BTW: do you know what is controlling the convergence rate ?

Comment: @SoManyProb_for_a_broken_heart. No worries. I don't know about the convergence rate. Also, I've clarified what I meant by convergence in the answer to avoid confusion with convergence in the EM algorithm (apologies if this wasn't clear originally).